# Find & Replace Many Different URLs in MySQL for WordPress Site

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

hopefully my headline made some sense.

I need to update URLs in a WordPress MySQL database. I have a spreadsheet of old URLs (around 400) that need to point to new URLs. All old URLs are down column A, and new ones are down column B.

Is there a way to be able to replace one with the other by way of some voodoo that will replace A1 with B1, A2 with B2 etc in the MySQL database?

Thank team. Hope you are well.

Note: I have not tried anything as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have following columns in your excel sheet;

`old_url=Column A`
&
`new_url=Column B`

| old_url | new_url |
| --- | --- |
| abc_old.com | abc_new.com |
| 123_old.com | 123_new.com |

You can introduce a third column and put formula that matches for following query:

```
UPDATE table_name t SET t.url='abc_new.com' WHERE t.url='abc_old.com';
```

Formula in excel would be:

```
="update table_name t set t.url='"&B2&"' where t.url='"&A2&"';"
```

This will populate all records accordingly. Then you can execute the queries in your database server

Comment: Wow that was quick. Thank you. 

So run that formula to achieve the query (let's say column C), and then copy all of column C and execute in PHPMyAdmin as a single query?

Comment: Not single query, they will be multiple queries, you  can run them all at once and it will work

Comment: Top shelf thanks again. Much appreciated.